# LabView doesn't unload dll when called in development environment

Tags: dll, labview

I have a LabView application that uses an external C DLL. When I run my application in the development environment, the DLL is blocked even after the the app is closed.

When I want to overwrite or delete the DLL, I have to first close LabView completely.

Is this a known issue? Can anyone offer a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you must do two things in your LabVIEW application:

1. Specify the path to the library on the block diagram rather than in the configuration dialog (which changes LabVIEW's behavior from load-time linking to run-time linking).
2. When you're done using the DLL node, wire a null path to tell LabVIEW that you're done using it (which causes Windows' reference count to decrement to 0 and the OS will unlock the file).

More details here: [Can I Dynamically Load and Unload a DLL in LabVIEW?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/77594203D78D12278625729100758BE5)

Comment: It isn't so much a "known problem" as a "design decision". LabVIEW has a single process for both the running code and the IDE, unlike other debuggers that have a separate process. It simplifies some things and makes others harder. But it is a deliberate choice of the designers.

Comment: Does this approach also work with .NET DLLs?